# Adding rows with value "0" for missing rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add missing rows based on the column "id" in a dataframe. The id should be continuous integers, starting from 1 to 60000. A small example is as follows: id ranges from 1 to 5. So I need to add 1,3,4 with value "0"s for the table below.

| id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 13 | 33 |
| 5 | 45 | 24 |

The final dataframe would become

| id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 13 | 33 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 45 | 24 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set column `'id'` as index, then use `reindex` method to conform `df` to new index with index from 1 to 5. The `reindex` method places `NaN` values in locations that had no values in the previous index, so you use `fillna` method to fill these with 0s, then reset the index and finally cast `df` to `int` dtype:

```
df = df.set_index('id').reindex(range(1,6)).fillna(0).reset_index().astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   id  value1  value2
0   1       0       0
1   2      13      33
2   3       0       0
3   4       0       0
4   5      45      24
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the DataFrame.append method: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

It adds rows to a DataFrame

You could use something like the following:

```
for i in [1, 3, 4]:
    df = df.append({'id':i, 'value1': 0, 'value2': 0}, ignore_index=True)
```

If you want them to be in order by id afterwards, you could sort it:

```
df.sort_values(by=['id'], inplace=True)
```